# SharePoint 2010 Employee Directory --- best solution?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

What is the best way to create Employee Directory on SharePoint 2010?

*No. of Employees is about 20

*All I need to show is 1)Name, 2)Phone, and 3)Office Communicator Presence

*I have looked at Site Users Web Part but I am struggling to understand how to add phone numbers into it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only 20 employees and want something quick and easy, I'd just do a Contact or Custom List. Since you only want to show 3 fields (which could actually be rolled into 2), I would lean more towards the custom list with a renamed Title field as your Phone field and then a Person or Group field for both Name and Presence. Set the column order in your view to show the new Person or Group column first, and then the phone number column.

This won't be synced to your AD in any way, so it will need to be maintained, but you will be able to have this set up and running in SharePoint Foundation in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: Wow thank you for reply. OK but I thought creating 20 rows by manually entering names & phone will take a long time. But I give a shot.